How to check if a MongoDB database exists using MongoDB driver Client in Laravel?
I am creating a mongodb database using MongoDB driver's Client in Laravel. This is my code;
use MongoDB\Client as MongoClient;

$databaseName     = 'little_buds';
$collectionName   = 'test'; 

$client           = new MongoClient();       // Connect to MongoDB server                        
$database         = $client->$databaseName;  // Dynamically create a database                        
$database->$collectionName->insertOne(array('key' => 'value'));  // Insert a document into the collection

Now, I want to check if the database 'little_buds' actually exists or not. How can I do it using Mongo Client in Laravel?
PS- I am using Laravel 9

Have you checked out listDatabaseNames?
